# Keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7 without the CTRL + ALT part?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to make a keyboard shortcut in Windows without <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>? I want one where pressing keypad 5 would execute a program on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right-click a shortcut to the program you want to make the keyboard shortcut to.
2. Click **Properties**.
3. Next to `Shortcut key:`, type <kbd>5</kbd> (from the number pad).

   - **Note:** <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> may need to be on.
4. Click **OK** or **Apply**.

[image: Shortcut properties]

Comment: That's odd. When I do it on my computer, it automatically fills in `Ctrl` + `Alt`. So can you show us a screen capture of your solution which doesn't include these two keys?

Comment: @Randolph, I can confirm @wizlog's answer. It works if `Num Lock` is on.

Comment: @RandolphWest I updated my answer to include a picture.